# C: operator -> and *

Tags: c, pointers, struct, postfix-operator

On the following example:

```
typedef struct {
    const char *description;
    float value;
} swag;

typedef struct {
    swag *swag;
    const char *sequence;
} combination;

typedef struct {
    combination numbers;
    const char *make;
} safe;

int main()
{
    swag gold = {"GOLD!", 1000000.0};
    combination numbers = {&gold, "6502"};
    safe s = {numbers, "RAMACON250"};

    //Correct handling
    printf("Result: %s \n", s.numbers.swag->description);

    //Faulty handling
    // printf("Result: %s \n", s.numbers.(*swag).description);

    return 0;
}
```

the following line is correct in order to receive the `"GOLD!"`

```
printf("Result: %s \n", s.numbers.swag->description);
```

but why the following is not correct as the `(*x).y` is same as `x->y`

```
printf("Result: %s \n", s.numbers.(*swag).description);
```

I receive the following fault during compilation:

> C:\main.c|26|error: expected identifier before '(' token|)

Comment: `printf("Result: %s \n", (*s.numbers.swag).description);`

Comment: Brackets in wrong place  `(*s.numbers.swag).description`, not `s.numbers.(*swag).description`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use

```
printf("Result: %s \n", ( *s.numbers.swag).description);
```

According to the C grammar the postfix expression `.` is defined the following way

```
postfix-expression . identifier
```

So you may write for example

```
( identifier1 ).identifier2
```

but you may not write

```
identifier1.( identifier2 )
```

Returning to your program you could even write

```
printf("Result: %s \n", ( *( ( ( s ).numbers ).swag ) ).description);
```

Answer (score 3):

> why the following is not correct as the (*x).y is same as x->y
>
> ```
> printf("Result: %s \n", s.numbers.(*swag).description);
> ```

You are correct about `(*x).y` being the same as `x->y`

But that is **not** what you do in the code:

```
s.numbers.(*swag).description
```

Look at it like this:

```
when comparing s.numbers.swag->description to x->y

x is s.numbers.swag
y is description

so by simple substitution

x->y equivalent to (*x).y becomes (*s.numbers.swag).description
```

Answer (score 2):

Just replace *swag with swag[0].

```
printf("Result: %s \n", s.numbers.swag[0].description);
```

Remember *swag and swag[0], are just the same thing.

Comment: That works, though if `swag` is logically a pointer to a single item, not a pointer to an array of items, it gives the erroneous impression that `swag` is an array. The OP was looking for reasons more than options here (after all, they already knew `->` worked), so a new option with no explanation for why the original approach didn't work isn't super helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The `.` and the `->` have the same operator precedence and their associatitivy is from left to right. That is why

```
s.numbers.swag->description
```

works fine. And, intuitively, you can follow what is resolved, from left to right.
You access `s` then `numbers` then `swag`, which you dereference to access `description`.

The mistake you make is to conclude that, *because `a->b` is equivalent to `(*a).b`*, the expression

```
s.numbers.(*swag).description
```

should be equivalent to the above one. That is not the case.

That is because the (unary) `*` operator has a lower precedence than `.` and `->`, and its associativity is from right to left, and putting the parenthesis does not fix that (You want to access the `swag` pointer and not the `swag` member).

What that effectively does is: Access `s` then `numbers` then the dereferenced `swag` (of numbers) and try to access `description`. But `numbers` only has a pointer to `swag` and not a `swag` member.

Equivalent expressions had been mentioned in another answer already, which I repeat here for completeness:

```
(*s.numbers.swag).description
```

Access `s` then `numbers` then `swag` and dererence to access description.
Remember `.` has a higher precedence than `*` and parenthesis is resolved before the `.` to access description because of the associatity from left to right.

```
s.numbers.swag[0].description
```

Access `s` then `numbers` then `swag` and dereference to access description.
The `[]` operator has same precedence and associativity as `.`. So you can read that expression from left to right.